# Detect conflict when uploading document to Google Drive

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-docs, merge-conflict-resolution

My Android app updates a Google Drive document. The file can be modified also elsewhere (e.g. through Drive web interface), so there may be a conflict on file upload. However, this should rarely happen. That's why I don't want my app to first query the revision history (since this is in most cases unnecessary) and only after that, update the file. *How can I detect that there is a conflict when updating the file?*

My investigation so far reveals that [getHeadRevisionId() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20056153/1097104) although the [null head revision id has been reported fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13426735/1097104).
Another thing I tried was setEtag() on the file before update(). [It should have given me error on update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11320975/1097104), but the upload was successful even the file had been changed remotely! Is this the correct way to use ETag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `If-Match` HTTP header:

```
final Update update = mService.files().update(mDriveFile.getId(), mDriveFile, byteContent);
final HttpHeaders headers = update.getRequestHeaders();
headers.setIfMatch(mDriveFile.getEtag());
update.setRequestHeaders(headers);
mDriveFile = update.execute();
```

In case the document has changed meanwhile, the update will get rejected with a response something like:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 412 Precondition Failed
{
  "code": 412,
  "errors": [
    {
      "domain": "global",
      "location": "If-Match",
      "locationType": "header",
      "message": "Precondition Failed",
      "reason": "conditionNotMet"
    }
  ],
  "message": "Precondition Failed"
}
```

Note that [ETag might change even if the content does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12065231/google-drive-file-etag).

Comment: How to use this approach on v3? There was an [File.getEtag() in v2](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/model/File.html#getEtag()), but it's [gone in v3](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/).

Answer (score 1):

**"Is this the correct way to use ETag?"**

Yes

Also, for non-Docs files, you should also check md5Checksum for changes to the content.

Comment: So, if it was the correct way to use ETag, why didn't my file update fail?

Comment: Can you paste the http request and response.

Comment: My suspicion is that setEtag() is not setting the If-Match header. You will probably need to set it manually. Seeing the http request should confirm this.

Comment: A couple of questions: 1. How do I log the headers (tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/3303131/1097104 without success)? 2. How do I set the headers manually, can I somehow set it as part of my mService.files().update(...).execute() command?

Comment: (1) see http://code.google.com/p/google-http-java-client/wiki/Android#Logging  (2) The Java client library gives you access to the underlying http transport. I can't find a quick link to paste for you. This is actually a good topic for a separate SO question.

Comment: 1. Thanks, now I'm able to log HTTP headers. 2. I followed your advice and asked a separate question http://stackoverflow.com/q/21968822/1097104

Comment: I don't see ETag in [v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource). What to use for "if-match" header to detect conflict in v3?