# Set HTTP header in Drive request

Tags: android, http-headers, google-drive-api, google-http-client

I want to detect conflict when updating a file to Drive. To accomplish this, [it seems I have to set the `If-Match` header](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21793871/1097104).

Currently, I update the doc to Google Drive with this one-liner:

```
mDriveFile = mService.files().update(mDriveFile.getId(), mDriveFile, byteContent).execute();
```

What is the simplest way to add the `If-Match` header in the request? [Example in Files: update documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/update) does not tell how to set HTTP headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the headers from `Update` object, add your own and put them back before executing the HTTP request:

```
final Update update = mService.files().update(mDriveFile.getId(), mDriveFile, byteContent);
final HttpHeaders headers = update.getRequestHeaders();
headers.setIfMatch("TheETagStoredFromDownload");
update.setRequestHeaders(headers);
mDriveFile = update.execute();
```